# Using context:property-placeholder location with Spring EL

Tags: spring, spring-el

I'm trying to use a property-placeholder to load some properties files, and I want to specify the name of one of the files using a system property, so that I can load different files based on the environment that my app runs in.

Initially I tried the following:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:environment_common.properties,classpath:environment_${app_env}.properties" />
```

I validated that the system property (app_env) is set correctly (e.g., "bar"), but Spring is loading the wrong file, (e.g., environment_foo.properties).

I tried using SpEL next:

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="#{ 'classpath:environment_common.properties,classpath:environment_'.concat(systemProperties['app_env'] }.properties) }" />
```

But it appears that `context:property-placeholder` doesn't support SpEL:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/#{'classpath:environment_common.properties]
```

It looks as though `context:property-placeholder` has its own parser looking for commas to delimit multiple property files, but its not first passing the value to SpEL to evaluate it.

How should I be using `context:property-placeholder`, or should I just bypass it and use `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` directly?

Comment: Bugreported: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11072

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried to use SpEL directly in a property-placeholder element. There appears to be [a bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7765) filed for it, though. As a rather simple workaround:

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="props" />
<util:properties id="props" location="#{ your expression here }"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem today. Here is my solution:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" 
        value="classpath:#{(T(java.lang.System).getProperty('my.property', 'development.properties'))}"/>
</bean>
```

I didn't use the predefined variable systemProperties but suppose that you could if you wanted to.